# C# Formatting DateTime giving me wrong result

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format

I'm trying to format a DateTime in a C# function, but I can't get it to work.

The format I'm trying to get is like this:

```
"28/02/2012"
```

I've tried different ways to format the DateTime, for example:

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

string formattedDate = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Today);
```

Both these examples are giving me this result:

```
"28.02.2012"
```

I've formatted DateTimes many times before using the two ways shown above, but I can't really see why I'm getting "." instead of "/".

Is there some configuration that has to be set up or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

phoog has given the correct reason, but I would suggest the wrong workaround. If you always want to format the date/time as if you were in a particular culture (probably the *invariant culture*) then you can do that:

```
string formattedDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I find this cleaner than forcing *some* parts of the format into an invariant form, while leaving others (the numbers) up to the culture. For example, consider this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        string formattedDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Console.WriteLine(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Today, that prints "06/04/1433" - which is appropriate for the Islamic calendar, but probably *isn't* what you expected.

Comment: I'm quite sure that some developers use Jon Skeet jokes where a Chuck Norris one would be suitable.

Comment: +1 Of course Jon is right.  My answer betrays my history with VB 6; the invariant culture is much more idiomatic for .NET.

Answer (score 6):

The `/` character in a date-time format string is *a placeholder for the culture-specific date separator.*  To specify the `/` character explicitly, you need to escape it: `"dd\\/MM\\/yyyy"` or `@"dd\/MM\/yyyy"`

For more information, see [the MSDN page "Custom Date and Time Format Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: And escape the escape character :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
string formattedDate = (String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", DateTime.Today)).Replace(".", @"/");
```